# Form Thumbnail URL for SharePoint large video Files

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to form SharePoint file's thumbnail URL (in Office 365) as mentioned in https://www.techmikael.com/2020/01/retrieving-thumbnailspreviews-for.html. This uses SharPoint site ID, List ID and file item's Unique ID to generate thumbnail URL.
`/_api/v2.0/sites/${this.context.pageContext.site.id}/lists/${listId}/items/${itemUniqueId}/driveItem/thumbnails/0/${maxHeight}/content${noRedirect}`

But I always get error message 404 Not Found. I used search API to verify that the thumbnail URL exists in "PictureThumbnailURL" field.

I also tried with _api/v2.1/... but get the same error. Just to be sure I ran the sample SPFx web part solution available here: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/js-msgraph-thumbnail and get the same 404 Not Found error for images.

I have already been using getpreview.ashx but I don't see preview for large video files but get the preview URL in the search even for those large files.

I can't use search API since search result may not be immediately available to get and save the thumbnail URL.

Is there any other way to get the picture thumbnail URL using REST API in SPFx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to generate the thumbnail URL using drive API. There are properties on File object VroomDriveID and VroomItemID. Using these properties we can format the link as below:

```
https://{tenantname}.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.1/drives/${VroomDriveID}/items/${VroomItemID}/thumbnails/0/c400x99999/content?preferNoRedirect=true
```

Below is sample code to get these properties from SharePoint:

```
let thumbnailURL = "";
let uniqueID = "{file's unique id}";
let resolution = "c400x99999";
let caml: ICamlQuery = {
ViewXml:
<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UniqueId' /><Value Type='Text'>${uniqueID}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>
};
// get list items
const fileItems: IItems = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("DocLibTitle").getItemsByCAMLQuery(caml, 'FieldValuesAsText, File/VroomDriveID,File/VroomItemID');
console.log("Items: ", fileItems);
let VroomDriveID = fileItems[0]["File"]["VroomDriveID"];
let VroomItemID = fileItems[0]["File"]["VroomItemID"];
thumbnailURL = "https://{tenantname}.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.1/drives/${VroomDriveID}/items/${VroomItemID}/thumbnails/0/${resolution}/content?preferNoRedirect=true";
console.log(thumbnailURL);
```

I hope this helps!